# How to remove all users and reset the primary key of user table in django?

Tags: django, reset, django-users

I'm developing a django application with some complicated user interactions and multi user types . So this requires a lot of testing to do . I've observed that even after deleting the user's table completely if I add a new user, the primary key of the newly added user isn't 1 . Is there an easy way to completely delete and reset all the primary key indices of the use table ?

Details :

1. Django version = 3.0
2. Using the default User model provided by django
3. Using dbsqlite3

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#sqlsequencereset

Answer (score 0):

You also need to delete the migrations folder in whichever app you have defined your custom users.

In the app foo, the folder foo/migrations contains all the data that you already changed and stored, for it to be a complete reset you must delete those.

Comment: There was only one file __init__.py I deleted it(no problems occurred) but even now the issue is still in effect